# Wallet initialization failed: basic_string::resize

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I just transferred a demo wallet from MyMonero.com to simplewallet, refreshed the wallet using the node.monerohash.com public node and saved it. Afterwards, when trying to set auto-refresh to 1 it asked for a password but said my initial password was incorrect. That's why I closed the wallet and wanted to re-open it.

I open it using this parameter on Windows

> simplewallet --wallet-file xx --password yy --daemon-host node.monerohash.com --rpc-bind-port 18082

*Sidenote: As it was only for testing purposes, both xx and yy only consist of lowercase letters and are fairly short. My computer is also not suitable to run a full node.*

Now I cant open my wallet anymore - the password checks out but it immediately crashes afterwards. As I am stuck on bad wifi and refreshing took more than an hour I would prefer not having to re-do it. If I have to do so, I would like to prevent this problem from happening again.

```
2016-Aug-28 22:46:52.097101 Monero 'Hydrogen Helix' (v0.9.3.0-release)
2016-Aug-28 22:46:52.097101 Setting log level = 0
2016-Aug-28 22:46:52.097101 default_log: C:\Temp\Monero\simplewallet.log
2016-Aug-28 22:46:52.098101 Logging at log level 0 to C:\Temp\Monero\simplewallet.log
2016-Aug-28 22:46:52.098101 Loading wallet...
2016-Aug-28 22:46:52.163105 Loaded wallet keys file, with public address: 45FZMgNtBQ7ZnhdKvJNDDyNqcAg8GxcXtQtt42qYtf7uHqmcic8K2K7YP4xiXfa5r94bhY6mYpLByCPQ4kENsZyiV8QQguy
2016-Aug-28 22:46:53.510182 ERROR C:/msys32/DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/simplewallet/simplewallet.cpp:2721 Wallet initialization failed: basic_string::resize
```

Comment: Was the wallet created on the same OS/machine as you're opening it on ?

Comment: Yes, exactly same device and nothing changed.

Comment: Either your wallet cache got corrupted (it can happen, it's not a database), or there is a bug. In both cases, you can delete the cache (X, if the keys is X.keys) and it will recreate it. It'd be helpful if you could check the size of file X first, then try again to create/load and see if it works, then check the size of X. If it still breaks, there's a weird bug somewhere that it'd be good to fix.

Comment: What is the error message? Can you share screenshots?

Comment: I recreated the wallet now multiple times and it looks like the problem is in the generation of the wallet - i can't open wallets that i generated via `simplewallet --generate-from-keys wallet` anymore. After successful creating it (verified file existence) i exit the wallet via `exit` (tried `save` before as well) and as soon as i try to open it again i get `failed to load wallet: input stream error`. I want to note that i don't have admin rights in case that may be important.

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://monero.stackexchange.com/posts/1390/edit) button and add the details to yoiur question instead of adding comments.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please open a bug on https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/issues, and add the exact command lines and data used (you can use a throwaway wallet seed), whether your OS is 32 or 64 bits, and the exact version of simplewallet you are using. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Created: https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/issues/1019

Comment: If this a new wallet which contains no monero ? If so, and you don't mind using another wallet from now on, it would be useful to add those wallet files plus the password to a bug on github, and never use it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very likely that this (at least the reversion to watch only) is due to a bug in 0.9.3, which is fixed in 0.9.4.

Note that the 32 bit Windows binaries for 0.9.4 mistakenly include 0.9.3 instead. This will be fixed shortly, see https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/issues/1019 for reference.

Comment: Thank you. That must be it, because it works fine under 32-bit linux.

Comment: I can confirm that the bug is fixed in 0.10.0, and most likely would have been closed in 0.9.4 if that version was available for win32 (all downloads included a repacked 0.9.3). As, according to fluffy, the win32 VM crashed it wasnt feasible to compile it in time, hence the long waiting period for 0.10.0.