# basic_string::resize crash

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, error-log

My simplewallet (W-XP) also crashes when loading a pre-existing wallet. This happens whether running against my local node or remote node. Deleting the wallet's cache enables it to load, but in watch-only mode.

The message is:

> Error: failed to load wallet: basic_string::resize

[image: Screenshot]

FWIW, here is the log:

```
2016-Aug-29 07:58:49.718750 Error: failed to load wallet: basic_string::resize 2016-Aug-29 07:58:49.718750 ERROR C:/msys32/DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/simplewallet/simplewallet.c‌​pp:1006 failed to open account 2016-Aug-29 07:58:49.718750 ERROR C:/msys32/DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/simplewallet/simplewallet.c‌​pp:2750 Failed to initialize wallet
```

Comment: http://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1380/100